# Footer div is randomly expanding to the full height of the container and covering all Wordpress post content

Tags: html, wordpress, connectivity, document.write

It doesn't happen every single time I load a page, but randomly a large black box will appear, covering all of the post content. Using the Inspector in Chrome's Developer Tools, what appears to be happening is that the footer div (which has a black background) has decided to expand to a height of 10,000px, thereby obscuring all of the post content. 
[inspector from Firefox showing black box dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hc9x.jpg)

The console shows the following error:

> A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script, , is >invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY be blocked >by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor network connectivity. >If blocked in this page load, it will be confirmed in a subsequent console >message. See  for more details.

...which seems to be related to the ad plugin Broadstreet.

Tech support mentioned that the CDN was disabled--could poor connectivity possibly have anything to do with this, that enabling the CDN would fix?

They also recommended the following solution, which is a bit technical for me:
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write

Comment: The website is baltimorefishbowl.com

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to check on some live example. May be the problem is due to some element (or it's child) before your footer element having `float: left` or `float:right`.

If so just add this css to the element immediately before your footer element:

```
.elementBeforeFooter:after{
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

Let me know if the problem is not due to any floating element. If possible, please share you live project or example demo.